# Dynamic routing catch all with symfony2

Tags: symfony, controller, routes

I have my own routing system I would like to send each call to one controller and in the controller I will detect which route/content I will display.

How to write this in the routing.yml so I can send each call to one controller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could do it with a catch all route like

```
catch_all:
    path: /{catch_all}
    defaults:
        _controller: Your:Controller:AndAction
    requirements:
        catch_all: "[\s\S]+"
```

That should catch all paths and pass them into your controller as the "catch_all" parameter, from there you could do what ever you want with it.

Comment: Thanks! Is this (catch_all: "[\s\S]+") better then this: (catch_all: ".+")